# Javascript async function instead of new promise

Tags: javascript

I just learnt "**async**" that "**async**" ensures that the function returns promise then i tried to make a promise with writing "**async**" instead of writing "**new Promise**" and it didn't work out so i want to know is it wrong syntax or it will never work out and i will have to write only **new promise**?

---

// This is a code

```
async function gets(){
    let gets1 = async()=>{
        return 45;
    }
    gets1.then((value)=>{
        console.log(value, "inside gets1")
    })
}
gets()
```

Comment: `async` use with `await`. `await functionCall()`.

Comment: Since you don't use any `await` you don't need `async function gets` but just `function gets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call the function

It should be `gets1().then()` and not `gets1.then()`

```js
async function gets(){
    let gets1 = async()=>{
        return 45;
    }
    gets1().then((value)=>{
        console.log(value, "inside gets1")
    })
}
gets()
```

Comment: He's gonna have a lot more problems when he realises that the result (if he decides to return anything) from `gets1()` isn't available out of this scope. Also, the outer function declaration doesn't need to be `async`.

Comment: Do you mean returning from `gets`? I don't really understand the issue.

Comment: See [Roko C. Buljan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73999543/2902996) for more coding context. Essentially, you don't want to mix `async/await` with `.then` in a function for more reasons than I can type here.

Comment: Actually i was just trying to write with different combination to get different result like a experiment what possible outcome it could return. I want to get result form gets1, i wanted to make the function as a promise however "async" ensures the function is a promise so i want to use then( ) to get the result. however i have got the answer that i forgot to call the function gets1( ).then( ).

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, you need to *call* a function `fn().then(`, not just reference it `fn.then(`.
Also if you don't use the `await`, you also don't need the wrapping `await`

```js
const gets = () => {
  const gets1 = async() => {
    return 45;
  }
  gets1().then((value) => {
    console.log(value, "inside gets1")
  })
};

gets();
```

Or use `async` with `await` to get rid of `Promise.then()`:

```js
const gets = async () => {
  const gets1 = async() => {
    return 45;
  };
  const value = await gets1();
  console.log(value, "inside gets1")
};

gets();
```

Make sure to read top to bottom: [async Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing will work without the outer `async` function too:

```js
let gets1 = async()=>"msg from gets1";
gets1().then(console.log)
```